# Find the values of sinθ and cosθ if tanθ = -7/24 and θ is reflex

Tags: trigonometry

I've tried to use the fact that $\tanθ = \frac{\sinθ}{\cosθ}.$

and the property $\sin^2θ + \cos^2θ = 1$ and trying to solve for sinθ but i'm running around in circles.

Also tried using the special triangles but the values i'm getting are way bigger than 1

Comment: $\theta$ is reflex... What does that mean?

Comment: Hints:  $(-7)^2+4^2=65$, $\tan\theta=\dfrac{-7/\sqrt{65}}{4/\sqrt{65}}$

Comment: @zoli A [reflex angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Types_of_angles) is an angle with measure greater than $180^\circ$ but less than $360^\circ$.

Comment: I see the question was edited and $4$ was changed to $24$ since my last comment

Answer (score 0):

$\sin\theta=-\dfrac74\cos\theta$. So,

$$\dfrac{49}{16}\cos^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$$

$$\cos^2\theta=\dfrac{16}{65}$$

As $\theta$ is reflex and $\tan\theta<0$, we have $\cos\theta>0$ and $\sin\theta<0$.

$\cos\theta=\dfrac4{\sqrt{65}}$ and $\sin\theta=-\dfrac7{\sqrt{65}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of $\sin x $ over $\cos x$ is $7/4$

$$7^2+4^2=65$$

Thus you have $\sin x =\pm 7/ {\sqrt {65}} $ and $\cos x =\mp 4/{\sqrt {65}}$

With the condition of being reflex you have positive $\cos x$ and negative $\sin x $

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The notation was obscuring simple algebra for me.

Using:
$$tanθ = sinθ/cosθ$$ and $$sin^2θ+cos^θ=1$$

We know $$tanθ = -7/24$$

therefore, $$sinθ/cosθ = -7/24$$

square the equation to get, $$sin^2θ/cos^2θ=49/576$$

use identity to get, $$sin^2θ/1-sin^2θ=49/576$$

rearrange to get, $$576sin^2θ=49(1-sin^2θ)$$

keep simplifying until we get $$sin^2θ=49/625$$

and therefore $$sinθ=-7/25$$ (negative because it's reflex and thus in 3rd quadrant.)

Can find cosθ using similar steps to give $24/25$

I would have spotted the solution quicker if I just replaced sinθ and cosθ with y for a simpler notation!